# Bootstrap Modal popup is disappearing after summitting data in Yii2?

Tags: ajax, yii2

I have a Modal popup which disappears after submitting the form's data, however the model is designed to return the answers on the same view, it works correctly independently, however it is not working that way as a popup. How do I keep the popup after submitting the data? I think the problem might be on the Controller. Thanks.

The mypopup view:

```
<div class="site-popup">
    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-5">
            <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'popup-form']); ?>
                <?= $form->field($model, 'pattern')->textArea(['rows' => 1]) ?>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <?= Html::submitButton('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'popup-button']) ?>
                </div>

            <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
        </div>
</div>

 <?php
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($model->data); 
 ?>
```

This is the view that call the mypopup:

```
 <p>
    <?= Html::button('Search', ['value' =>Url::to('index.php?r=site/mypopup'),'class' =>'btn btn-success', 'id'=>'modalButton']) ?>
 </p>
        <?php
            Modal::begin([
            'header'=> '<h4>Search</h4>',  
            'id' => 'modal',
            'size' => 'modal-lg',
            ]);

            echo "<div id='modalContent'></div>";

            Modal::end();
       ?>
```

The controller:

```
public function actionPopup()
{

 $model = new PopupForm();

   if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) 
   {
      $model->insertPopup();
         return $this->renderAjax('mypopup', ['model' => $model]);

            } else {
                return $this->renderAjax('mypopup', [
                    'model' => $model,
                ]);
            } 
}
```

The js file:

```
$(function(){
    //get the click of the search button
    $('#modalButton').click(function(){
        $('#modal').modal('show')
            .find('#modalContent')
            .load($(this).attr('value'));
        }); 
});
```

Comment: use pjax in your view http://blog.neattutorials.com/yii2-pjax-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use pjax in your view

> use yii\widgets\Pjax;

```
 <?php Pjax::begin(); ?>
   //your content
   <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'popup-form','options' => ['data-pjax' => true],]); ?>
    //form fields
   <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>   
   //your content
 <?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

Comment: I will try to enclose the whole ActiveForm inside Pjax, because inside Modal I have an ActiveForm.

Comment: Even if the ActiveForm comes from another model? @Vishva G

Comment: I have put this on the popup view and still have the same issue, what could be wrong ? thanks. `<?php Pjax::begin(); ?>
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'popup-form','options' => ['data-pjax' => true],]); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'pattern')->textArea(['rows' => 1]) ?>
  <div class="form-group">
      <?= Html::submitButton('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'pattern2-button']) ?>
                </div>
            <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
        </div>
 <?php
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($model->data); 
 ?>
 <?php Pjax::end(); ?> `

Comment: what is happening know

Comment: The popup is still disappearing. @Vishva G

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have overcome the issue, this answer works, however it could be improved.

This link states: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-responses.html#response-body

> When the current request is an AJAX request, sending a Location header will not automatically cause the browser to redirect. To solve
>   this problem, the yii\web\Response::redirect() method sets an
>   X-Redirect header with the redirection URL as its value. On the
>   client-side, you may write JavaScript code to read this header value
>   and redirect the browser accordingly.
>
> Info: Yii comes with a yii.js
>   JavaScript file which provides a set of commonly used JavaScript
>   utilities, including browser redirection based on the X-Redirect
>   header. Therefore, if you are using this JavaScript file (by
>   registering the yii\web\YiiAsset asset bundle), you do not need to
>   write anything to support AJAX redirection. More information about
>   yii.js can be found in the Client Scripts Section.

By checking this link: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-response.html#redirect()-detail

So I modified the js file:

```
$(function(){

    $('#modalButton').click(function(){
            $('#modal').modal('show')
                .find('#modalContent')
                .load($(this).attr('value'));
            }); 

    $document.ajaxComplete(function (event, xhr, settings) {
        var url = xhr && xhr.getResponseHeader('index.php?r=site/mypopup');

        if (url) {
            window.location = url;
        }
    });

});
```

And the popup view:

```
<?php Pjax::begin(['enablePushState' => false]); ?>

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'popup-form', 'options' => ['data-pjax' => true],]); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'pattern')->textArea(['rows' => 1]) ?>

   <div class="form-group">
  <?= Html::submitButton('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'popup-button']) ?>
    </div>

   <?php

     echo "<pre>";
     print_r($model->data); 
    ?>

 <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
 <?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```